# Remove layers with arcpy- Error

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers, error-000732, remove

I use this code in order to remove layers that are out of the data frame of the map:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True  
env.workspace = r"G:\PROJECTS\kohav_yair_west\gis\aa"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles('*.mxd'):
        print '---' ,mxdname, '---'  
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(env.workspace, mxdname))  
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
        print 'REMOVED LYR'
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" ,df):
                if lyr.isGroupLayer == True: continue
                if lyr.isRasterLayer == True: continue
                arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr.dataSource, "lyr")
                frameLyr = r"G:\PROJECTS\kohav_yair_west\gis\layers\frame.shp"
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("lyr", "INTERSECT", frameLyr)
                if int(arcpy.GetCount_management("lyr").getOutput(0)) == 0:
                        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)
                        print u'Removed '+unicode(lyr) + ' lyr'
        print '---REMAIN LYR---'
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "" , df):
                print lyr.name
        mxd.save()        
del mxd
```

but i get this error and i don't understand what is the problem?

```
--- ttl.mxd ---
REMOVED LYR

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\desktop\y\yaron\Private\shonot\software\---gis---\tools\YARON_SCRIPTS\SelectLayerByLocation3.py", line 21, in <module>
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr.dataSource, "lyr")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6520, in MakeFeatureLayer
raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset F:\GIS\Updating_2014\ttl\arcview\ttl_all_blue_lines_07.05.shp does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).
```

This route : F:\GIS\Updating_2014\ttl\arcview\ttl_all_blue_lines_07.05.shp exist but the name of the layer is :"ttl_all_blue_lines_07.05.14.shp" and in the error it mention as ttl_all_blue_lines_07.05.shp

Comment: I smell a path issue here, use this `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr.dataSource.replace('\','\\'), "lyr")` instead of `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr.dataSource, "lyr")`

Comment: but the code works with other layers perfectly.

Comment: But in `F:\GIS\Updating_2014\ttl\arcview\ttl_all_blue_lines_07.05.shp` all `\t` translated into `  ` i.e. a tab so layers like this will have problem :( I think if this is the case then above comment should do the job for you for any kind of layers..

Comment: i get an error:   invalid encoding 'cp1255'

Comment: invalid encoding 'cp1255'. saving as UTF-8

Comment: please post the full error or traceback..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47743/discussion-between-newgis-and-sislam).